# Finding the second highest value in a row without subqueries SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am tasked to find the second highest salary in the company and then returning that salary and the employee who has that salary. The part that has me confused is trying to do this with no sub queries and we can only use the INTERSECT, UNION, and EXCEPT operators.

Comment: In a row? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the salaries are unique, you can just use:

```
select salary, employee
from t
order by salary desc
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Your question suggests that this is true because of the singular "employee" for the second salary.

If this is not true, use aggregation:

```
select salary, array_agg(employee)
from t
group by salary
order by salary desc
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```